# webrivers - cannot receive inline images from email using php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to retrieve email using php mail but i am unable to recieve Inline images. I am able to recieve text but not recieved images.

Below is **code i have tried :**

```
<?php
$emailAddress = "domain@domian.com"; 
$emailPassword = "password";
$domainURL = 'domian.com';
$useHTTPS = true;
$inbox = imap_open('{'.$domainURL.':143/notls}INBOX',$emailAddress,$emailPassword) or die('Cannot connect to domain:' . imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');
if($emails) {
rsort($emails);
foreach($emails as $email_number) {
$overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
$header = imap_headerinfo($inbox, $email_number);
echo $subject_other= $overview[0]->subject;
echo $sender_name_other= $overview[0]->from;
echo $date_other=$overview[0]->date;
echo $msg_to_other=$overview[0]->to;
echo $msg_from_other = $header->from[0]->mailbox . "@" . $header->from[0]->host;
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 2);
echo $message;
}
} 
imap_close($inbox);
?>
```

only receive text mail, cannot receive inline images how to fix it...please help me...

Comment: u should specify your header like $header = "From: $noreply@intaxfin.com\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";

Comment: you have to specify header

Comment: inline images show this format  how to fix it "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcU FhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj/2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgo KCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj/wgARCAHCAfQDASIA AhEBAxEB/8QAGwABAAIDAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUGAQMEBwL/xAAYAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AQIEA//aAAwDAQACEAMQAAAB9AHF1AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGjhJUAAAAAAAAAAAAAB8fYc VbluOKD8y+go6R1kAAAAAAAAAAAAchW7TQPRDIAAAAAAAAAAAGM8J3c3yl3RGuFl45vl6M3uip+t WWCag5zUCwAAAAAAA+IGWwuDvsAYzwm6gSVPL5aeXqAAAAAAAAAAMRuqEzdXV2Rs1jHxtjs53xWi "

Answer (score 1):

@Thiyaga rajan it seems that your image is sending as attachment. Use **`Base64_encryption`** this may work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify header for sending images in mail.